# Global and function environments: variable definition

Tags: r, global-variables

I had a question which seems weird to me. Why doesn't the following throw me an error?

```
foo <- function(a, b) {
  a <- 2
  a * b
}

b <- 7

foo(a, b)
[1] 14
```

but

```
exists("a")
[1] FALSE
```

Why am I wrong with the expectation that `foo(a, b)` should result in `Error: object 'a' not found`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo(a,b)` doesn't return an error because you set the variable `a <- 2` in the function itself. The function never actually uses the `a` that you pass through, and so you don't get an error.

If you comment `a<-2` out, then you will get the expected error. `exists` checks the global environment by default, and not the existence of variables created in functions.

Comment: You can see the result described in this answer by using `foo(3, 7)`. Still gives 14 !